# how to get what is not shown in the source of html page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax, jQuery and PHP scripting that returns more data from a database as I scroll down (infinite scroll until more data is in the database).
The thing is that each data is placed into a div with a unique id, but only the initial content (loaded when the page is entered for the first time) appears in the HTML source.
Once the more content is displayed, none of if appears in the HTML source code.

Anyone knows how to get to the ids of the divs that are loaded on scroll? I need like an explanation of what's going on.

thx

Comment: this is actually what I followed:http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Comment: Use a developer tool like Firebug to show you the current state of the page/dom (Try pressing F12 in your browser of choice)

Comment: Are you trying to get this information programmatically, or just to view while debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, you can install Firebug and watch the HTML change dynamically (with your eyes!!): http://getfirebug.com/

On Chrome, you can use the built-in Developer Tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

To get the id's of the elements that are loaded via AJAX, you'll want to use jQuery's `live` function.

Comment: I see the new divs loaded on the fly in Firebug, but not if I look back at the source code of HTML

Comment: Sounds like a separate question to me. "How do I get the id's of dynamically loaded HTML elements?" I bet it's already been asked :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also capture the `DOMNodeInserted` event.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
    console.log($(e.target));
});
```